# Are there any UV Coordinates (or similar) for UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, affinetransform

I have a simple `UIImageView` in my view, but I can't seem to find any feature in Apple's documentation to change the UV Coordinates of this `UIImageView`, to convey my idea to you, this GIF file should preview how changing 4 vertices coordinates can change how the image gets viewed on the final `UIImageView`.

I tried to find a solution online too (other than documentation) and found none.

[image]

I use [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_%28Apple_programming_language%29).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? See [The XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve that very animation using [`UIView.transform`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform) or [`CALayer.transform`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/transform). You'll need basic geometry to convert UV coordinates to a `CGAffineTransform` or `CATransform3D`.

I made an assumption that **affine** transform would suffice because in your animation the transform is affine (parallel lines stay parallel). In that case, 3 vertices are free -- the 4th one is constrained by the other 3.

If you have 3 vertices, you can compute the affine transform matrix using: [Affine transformation algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755771/affine-transformation-algorithm)

To achieve the infinite repeat, use [`UIImageResizingMode.Tile`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIImageResizingMode).