# Detecting perspective angle and performing perspective transform using OpenCV

Tags: android, c, opencv, computer-vision, image-recognition

I have some content to be feature-detected using OpenCV. Before applying detection to the content itself, I need to detect the angle of perspective distortion and fix it. Probably I can use the idea of how QR-code does it - add several anchors to the image. There won't be any square-shaped content, so the source image may look like:

[Source Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvkaq.jpg)

The 3 squares will be our anchors.

When using OpenCV, as far as I understand, I should do these operations:

1. Apply grayscale scheme to the image using `cvtColor` function.
2. Apply blur using `blur`or `GaussianBlur`.
3. Apply `threshold` and `Canny`.
4. Use `findContours` and analyze the results, find the 3 squares by checking vertices count or similar.
5. Apply the `perspectiveTransform` and `warpPerspective` functions to analyze the squares positions and apply the corresponding transform to the source image.

The problem is I actually don't understand which parameters should be used, and what is the order of methods calls in step #5.
I'm new to coding and maths, so I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I assume your main question is how to find a **transformation from three 2D correspondences** and warp an image accordingly.

Note that 3 points only define an **affine transformation**, not a perspective one. (Affine transformations are perfectly good if your viewing angle is small, for instance if an object is far away from the camera.)

A 2D affine matrix is a 3x3 matrix where the last row is `[0 0 1]`. (For a perspective matrix, the zero values may be arbitrary.)

You can calculate the affine transformation by solving one linear system, as described in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2756165/2079934.
(The solution is unique.)

When you have the affine matrix, you can apply `warpAffine` (not `warpPerspective`) to rectify the image.
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpaffine